# How can I get a Euro (€) sign with a MacBook Pro US keyboard in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, currency-format

I have a MacBook Pro running regularly on Windows 7 with direct boot into Windows.

I have a US keyboard but need to use the Euro sign all the time. I haven't managed to find a shortcut that works. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `Shift-Option-2` working?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number pad: Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type in 0128.

If you do not, try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+2

Comment: I am in Windows and tried holding the shift key at same time as the Option/Alt key and 2 - didn't work I am afraid. I am using MS Word to type the text.

Comment: One possible way is to open up the Character Map.  This is located at Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map.

Comment: The character map seems too complicated. I have now found that in MS Office I can use CTRL-ALT-E to get the euro sign. Nice and easy. But this won't work in Lotus Notes which is the company email client.

Comment: Is it possible to use an external keyboard with a numpad, then?